# Java is not finding my class's method

Tags: java

I've seen similar questions with answers that didn't solve my problem.

In the following code, I can create a `BookCard` object and call its `getAuthorField` method in other classes, but my IDE doesn't seem to be finding it from the particular class that needs it.

```
package com.company;

import com.SourceTypeCards.BookCard;
import com.SourceTypeCards.FilmCard;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class EditSourceDialog extends JDialog
{
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JButton buttonOK;
    private JButton buttonCancel;
    private JComboBox<Enum> typeOfSourceComboBox;
    private JPanel cards;

    JTextField authorNameField = new JTextField(20);

    JPanel bookCard = new BookCard();
    JPanel filmCard = new FilmCard();

    ...

    private void onOK()
    {
        System.out.println(bookCard.getAuthorField()); //CANNOT RESOLVE METHOD

        dispose();
    }
}
```

Why is my IDE/compiler not finding this method in this particular `EditSourceDialog` class?

**BookCard.java**

```
package com.SourceTypeCards;

import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * Created by Trevor on 14/07/2015.
 */
public class BookCard extends MainCard
{
    JLabel authorLabel;
    JLabel editorsLabel;
    JLabel yearPublishedLabel;
    JLabel titleLabel;

    CardTextField authorField;
    JCheckBox editorsCheckBox;
    CardTextField yearPublishedField;
    CardTextField titleField;

    ...

    public String getAuthorField()
    {
        return authorField.getText();
    }
}
```

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Please show the declaration of `BookCard` and `getAuthorField()`.

Comment: That's because you used `JPanel` in place of `BookCard`.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
JPanel bookCard = new BookCard();
```

to

```
BookCard bookCard = new BookCard();
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions with simple errors. Now this question will not be automatically cleaned up by the roomba, and without janitorial effort from other members it will live forever.

Comment: Facepalming myself at that oversight, thanks so much.

Comment: @TinyGiant should I delete this question? It's my first time posting so I just want to double-check before I do

Comment: @TrickyTrev You can't delete it anymore because it has an answer.

Comment: @TinyGiant There are plenty of closed questions with upvoted answers. If Stack Overflow wants to clean those up, it can do so site-wide. I am not going to delete this answer because of your opinion; SO is free to change how they clean-up questions if this type of question is undesirable.

Comment: This type of question is undesirable and it has been discussed and agreed upon multiple times on meta that questions like this should not stick around as they are not useful to anyone else and just add to bloat. But if you feel like poluting the site and making work for everyone else, there is nothing I can do but work to clean up after your mess.

Comment: @TinyGiant link to meta please?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281795/4639281 for starters, but you can find them pretty easily. Go to the tavern and ask "Should I answer bad questions that have a very clear reason to close?". The point of closing questions is to stop those questions from being answered and eventually get rid of them if they are not improved. There is no way of improving this question, therefore it should be deleted.